# Finding all possible combinations whose sum is within certain range of target

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I talked with some colleagues and the problem I currently have is actually quite challenging. The context behind this problem has to do with mass spectrometry and assigning structure to different peaks that the software gives.

But to break it down into a optimization problem, I have a certain target value. I also have a list of various inputs whose sum I want to be as close as possible to the target as possible.

**So as an example, here is what I have.**

```
List of inputs: [18.01, 42.01, 132.04, 162.05, 203.08, 176.03]

Target value: 1800.71
```

I want to find all the possible combinations of the inputs listed whose sum is within 0.5 of 1800.71. So the sum can be anywhere between 1800.21 and 1801.21.

I already know two inputs could be:

```
[18.01, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05, 162.05] **which gives a sum of 1800.59**
```

and

```
[18.01, 18.01, 203.08, 203.08, 203.08, 162.05, 203.08, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 18.01, 42.01, 162.05, 203.08, 203.08] **which gives a sum 1800.71**
```

I'm NOT looking to find the combination that gets me as close as possible to the target value; I am interested in ALL the possible combinations that are within 0.5 of the target value.

If anyone could help me with this problem I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: sounds like you're looking for some kind of a variation on the [coin change problem](https://hackernoon.com/the-coin-change-problem-explained-ddd035a8f22f)

Comment: Check out the docs for `itertools`, in particular, `combinations`, `permutations`, `product` and `chain`

Comment: How large is the dataset? For something quick and dirty permutations with 1, n in length would work, otherwise implement dynamic programming as shown in the coin change problem.

Comment: @MatsLindh The dataset isn't large. I have just a couple target values that I want to find combinations of inputs to. The challenge is that I'm trying to find combinations of the input that sum close to target value.

Comment: @Alan the question was, how many numbers can you choose from. I feel like this problem's complexity class is quite high, it won't scale easily beyond 10-20 numbers. I think python is the wrong language for this kind of problem, as it is notoriously slow.

Comment: @Finomnis The number of numbers you can choose from is the same as the one I have listed above so around 6-8. What language would you recommend? The only other two I know are R and Matlab.

Comment: Well, for prototyping python is quite good. But for performance, choose C/C++/Rust. But for 6-8 numbers, python is also sufficient, and does the job in <1s

Comment: @Alan you should award the 'correct answer' to someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of allowing multiple values, it would be a lot faster to just compute an integer factor for every value.

For your problem, I get 988 results.

```
import math
import time

def combinator(tolerance, target, inputs):

    # Special case for inputs with one element, speeds up computation a lot
    if len(inputs) == 1:
        number = inputs[0]
        result_min = int(math.ceil((target-tolerance)/number))
        result_max = int(math.floor((target+tolerance)/number))
        for factor in range(result_min, result_max+1):
            yield [factor]
        return

    # Special case for no inputs, just to prevent infinite recursion 
    if not inputs:
        return

    number = inputs[-1]
    max_value = int(math.floor((target + tolerance)/number))

    for i in range(max_value+1):
        for sub_factors in combinator(tolerance, target-i*number, inputs[:-1]):
            sub_factors.append(i)
            yield sub_factors

def main():
    inputs = [18.01, 42.01, 132.04, 162.05, 203.08, 176.03]
    target = 1800.71

    tolerance = 0.5

    t_start = time.perf_counter()
    results = list(combinator(tolerance, target, inputs))
    t_end = time.perf_counter()

    for result in results:
        result_str = ""
        result_value = 0
        for factor, value in zip(result, inputs):
            if not factor:
                continue
            if result_str != "":
                result_str += " + "
            result_str += "{}* {}".format(factor, value)
            result_value += factor*value
        print("{:.2f}".format(result_value) + " =\t[" + result_str + "]") 

    print("{} results found!".format(len(results)))
    print("Took {:.2f} milliseconds.".format((t_end-t_start)*1000))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
1801.00 =   [100* 18.01]
1800.96 =   [93* 18.01 + 3* 42.01]
1800.92 =   [86* 18.01 + 6* 42.01]
...
1800.35 =   [5* 18.01 + 3* 42.01 + 9* 176.03]
1800.33 =   [2* 42.01 + 1* 132.04 + 9* 176.03]
1800.35 =   [3* 18.01 + 1* 162.05 + 9* 176.03]
988 results found!
Took 11.48 milliseconds.
```

---

I also reimplemented the same algorithm in Rust.

Performance on your problem:

- Python: *~12 ms*
- Rust: *~0.7 ms*

Here is the code:

```
use std::time::Instant;

fn combinator(tolerance : f32, target: f32, inputs: &[f32]) -> Vec<Vec<i32>>{

    let number = match inputs.last() {
        Some(i) => i,
        None => return vec![]
    };

    if inputs.len() == 1 {
        let result_min = ((target-tolerance)/number).ceil() as i32;
        let result_max = ((target+tolerance)/number).floor() as i32;
        return (result_min..=result_max).map(|x| vec![x]).collect();
    }

    let max_value = ((target + tolerance)/number).floor() as i32;

    let mut results = vec![];
    for i in 0..=max_value {
        for mut sub_factors in combinator(tolerance, target - i as f32 * number, &inputs[..inputs.len()-1]) {
            sub_factors.push(i);
            results.push(sub_factors);
        }
    }

    results
}

fn print_result(factors: &[i32], values: &[f32]){
    let sum : f32 = factors.iter()
        .zip(values.iter())
        .map(|(factor,value)| *factor as f32 * *value)
        .sum();
    println!("{:.2} =\t[{}]", sum,
             factors.iter()
                    .zip(values.iter())
                    .filter(|(factor, _value)| **factor > 0)
                    .map(|(factor, value)| format!("{}* {}", factor, value))
                    .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                    .join(", "));
}

fn main() {
    let inputs = vec![18.01, 42.01, 132.04, 162.05, 203.08, 176.03];
    let target = 1800.71;

    let tolerance = 0.5;

    let t_start = Instant::now();
    let results = combinator(tolerance, target, &inputs);
    let duration = t_start.elapsed().as_micros() as f64;

    for result in &results {
        print_result(&result, &inputs);
    }

    println!("{} results found!", results.len());
    println!("Took {} milliseconds", duration / 1000.0);
}
```

```
1801.00 =   [100* 18.01]
1800.96 =   [93* 18.01, 3* 42.01]
1800.92 =   [86* 18.01, 6* 42.01]
...
1800.35 =   [5* 18.01, 3* 42.01, 9* 176.03]
1800.33 =   [2* 42.01, 1* 132.04, 9* 176.03]
1800.35 =   [3* 18.01, 1* 162.05, 9* 176.03]
988 results found!
Took 0.656 milliseconds
```

---

Also, just for fun, those are the exact solutions to your problem. There are 5 of them.

```
1800.71 =   [12* 18.01, 1* 42.01, 2* 162.05, 6* 203.08]
1800.71 =   [13* 18.01, 2* 42.01, 2* 132.04, 6* 203.08]
1800.71 =   [16* 18.01, 7* 42.01, 6* 203.08]
1800.71 =   [52* 18.01, 1* 42.01, 1* 132.04, 1* 162.05, 3* 176.03]
1800.71 =   [54* 18.01, 4* 42.01, 1* 132.04, 3* 176.03]
```

Comment: Nice to see the time comparisons.  I wrote a solution in JavaScript, which also outputs 988 solutions, and it runs in about 55ms:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mZpwOp

Comment: @RickHitchcock Not bad! I didn't realize that javascript is quite so fast by now. For me, it took 66ms(Chrome), 145ms(Firefox).

Comment: I've now gotten my JavaScript solution down to about 20ms.

Comment: I'm really impressed by that speed considering all the string conversions involved, well done

Answer (score 4):

Another answer in the same vein as the existing fine answers.  I found it simpler to use a range instead of a target + tolerance, and use a trivial (unoptimized) recursive solution, which seems fast enough to find the ~1000 answers to your use case.

Changing to use generators/yield or to optimize the single value case did not change the time taken for all results, though you may find it useful if you have a pipeline.

```
def fuzzy_coins(vals, lower, upper):
    '''
    vals: [Positive]
    lower: Positive
    upper: Positive
    return: [[Int]]
    Returns a list of coefficients for vals such that the dot
    product of vals and return falls between lower and upper.
    '''
    ret = []
    if not vals:
        if lower <= 0 <= upper:
            ret.append(())
    else:
        val = vals[-1]
        for i in xrange(int(upper / val) + 1):
            for sub in fuzzy_coins(vals[:-1], lower, upper):
                ret.append(sub + (i,))
            lower -= val
            upper -= val
    return ret
```

Even so, this takes ~100ms in python 2.7 and 3.6

```
[('1800.33', (0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 9)),
 ('1800.35', (3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9)),
 ('1800.35', (5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 9)),
 ('1800.38', (0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 6)),
 ('1800.38', (1, 11, 2, 0, 0, 6)),
...
 ('1800.92', (86, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
 ('1800.94', (88, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
 ('1800.96', (91, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)),
 ('1800.96', (93, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
 ('1801.00', (100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))]
Took 0.10885s to get 988 results
```

e.g. usage:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pprint
import time


def main():
    vals = [18.01, 42.01, 132.04, 162.05, 203.08, 176.03]
    target = 1800.71
    fuzz = .5

    lower = target - fuzz
    upper = target + fuzz
    start = time.time()
    coefs = fuzzy_coins(vals, lower, upper)
    end = time.time()
    pprint.pprint(sorted(
        ('%.2f' % sum(c * v for c, v in zip(coef, vals)), coef)
        for coef in coefs
    ))
    print('Took %.5fs to get %d results' % (end - start, len(coefs)))
```

Comment: I see what you did there. Very smart! Gonna try how fast this version runs in rust :)

Comment: Turns out, they are exactly the same speed. The only change that really did something was the vals[:-1] instead of the vals[1:], and that more than halfed the speed. So my rust implementation is now at 2.1ms :)

Comment: @Finomnis nice!  Glad to see a haskell habit still has a little benefit =)

Comment: Got the time down to 12ms, Rust version 0.7 ms ;)

Comment: Well done!  You can probably drop the math.floor since you int-cast it anyway, and maybe the ceil.  For me I didn't see much of a speedup doing the single-case, but I must have missed something.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `floor` can be removed, gave a minor speedup. Ceil is definitely necessary, though. Things go very wrong otherwise, especially because I don't have an additional check any more. My algorithm relies on result_max and result_min are correct. That's also why I think I will leave the `floor()` in there, it is just easier to understand.

Comment: Well, the reason you get that huge speedup for the single-case is that you iterate over ALL possible numbers of the last one, but instead you could compute which ones the valid ones are, reducing it down to a single one in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a recursion to get all combinations of values in input list, that sum of the combination is within the threshold. The output is in list `out` (Tuple of sum and combination list. I don't print it whole, because is quite big).

```
lst = [18.01, 42.01, 132.04, 162.05, 203.08, 176.03]
target = 1800.71

def find_combination(lst, target, current_values=[], curr_index=0, threshold=0.5):
    s = sum(current_values)

    if abs(s - target) <= threshold:
        yield s, tuple(current_values)

    elif s - target < 0:
        for i in range(curr_index, len(lst)):
            yield from find_combination(lst, target, current_values + [lst[i]], i)

    elif s - target > 0:
        curr_index += 1
        if curr_index > len(lst) - 1:
            return

        yield from find_combination(lst, target, current_values[:-1] + [lst[curr_index]], curr_index)

out = []
for v in find_combination(sorted(lst, reverse=True), target):
    out.append(v)

out = [*set(out)]

print('Number of combinations: {}'.format(len(out)))

## to print the output:
# for (s, c) in sorted(out, key=lambda k: k[1]):
#   print(s, c)
```

Prints:

```
Number of combinations: 988
```

EDIT: Filtered out the duplicates.